# Is my Github username bad if I want to use it for professional use in the future?

Tags: professionalism

My Github username is the same as this account's-BadassSalad.
Currently, I'm just a student, so I'm doing personal projects, but I was wondering if this username might hurt me in the future.

Maybe I'll make a whole new one when I do want to use Github in resumes? Comments/advices would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: This seems fairly speculative. You're asking if this *might* hurt me. I mean, yeah, it might...

Comment: Github provides option to change the username, right?

Comment: Nah. It's okai. Just have quality repos.

Comment: Na... it's fine... if you have to ask the question, then yep, it will get you the quality job you deserve

Comment: [Yuck](https://www.xkcd.com/37/)!

Comment: I can't upvote that enough!!!  :-)

Comment: FWIW, for me that one is fine.  It's not racist or vulgar.  Many programmers have "funny" nicknames - you have no problem there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can create a new account or [change your name](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-your-github-username/) with a more professional sounding name that is far less likely to potentially give a bad impression to people considering hiring you where you can keep the same content, why not? You can even realistically manage them separately to fill different needs. Maintaining only the polished code you feel proud of on your professional account.

*Thanks to [@Anish](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/36656/anish-sheela) for the [comment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/126664/is-my-github-username-bad-if-i-want-to-use-it-for-professional-use-in-the-future/126665#comment403016_126664) about changing names.